How is micro-batch-size influencing the throughput per GPU?
I am testing how is micro-batch-size influencing the throughput per GPU with a constant global-batch-size on Megatron-LM.
I have done several tests with a 400M transformer based model on 2 A40 GPUS, and only use data parallelism. Here are some training Arguments

With different test I only change the micro-batch-size , trained on 100 iterations with seq_len =1024 and global-batch-size =24 . Here are some result with different micro-batch-size

I print the log every 5 iterations with the megatron-LM native functionality and compute the averaged throughput per GPU through all iterations.
For each Iteration , the total computational complexity is the same , but throughput per GPU increases as the micro-batch-size increases. I know that may related to the GPU cache load or arithmetic intensity but not quite clear. Can anyone provide some in-depth explanations?

GPUs are designed for parallel processing. The GPU processes the full batch in parallel. This leads to higher throughput up to the point of saturating the GPU's capacity and/or memory
